# Producing a library with a recent gcc and consuming it with an older gcc - Why are there issues despite the same C++ version?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, libstdc++

Don't ask me why I am doing what I am doing... that would be a long story.
For now, the purpose of this post is to learn and to understand why things don't work the way I expect. Possibly my expectations are wrong ?

- So initially I build my own SystemC 2.3.3 library from source using a recent compiler, say **gcc 10.2.0**. However, to preserve backwards compatibility with older gccs, I request C++11 :

  ```
  ./configure CXXFLAGS="-DSC_CPLUSPLUS=201103L"
  ```
- Next I want to build an application using an older gcc that supports C++11 (and the same ABI), say **gcc 8.2.0**, :

  ```
  g++ -std=c++11 sc_main.cpp -I/path/to/systemc/include -L/path/to/systemc/lib -lsystemc -lm -o sim
  ```

To my surprise, link fails:

```
libsystemc.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream()
```

In effect, comparing the outputs of

```
nm --demangle `/path/to/gcc/10.2.0/bin/g++ --print-file-name libstdc++.so` | grep "std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::"
```

and

```
nm --demangle `/path/to/gcc/8.2.0/bin/g++ --print-file-name libstdc++.so` | grep "std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::"
```

reveals some differences. Indeed, the former contains `std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream()` whereas the latter doesn't.

Is this expected ? **Does it mean that in general, it is necessary but not sufficient** for the producer and the consumer of a library to use the same C++ version (and the same ABI) ? Or is there something else going on that I don't understand ?

Comment: Code librarian Titus Winters would say "Compile everything — ABSOLUTELY EVERYTHING — with the same flags, at the same time, with the same compiler, or fear the wrath of the ODR gods."  Could be what you are experiencing.

Comment: @user17732522: yes these are the actual version I tested... I have found that if I consume the library with gcc 9.3.0 it all works nicely, but if I consume with anything older than that, it fails as described.

Comment: Note to the curious: I had to add the `--dynamic` flag to `nm` to see anything in my `libstdc++.so`

Comment: @Eljay: well yes I hear what you are saying, except it is not a practical usage model. In this specific example I happen to be both the producer and the consumer of the library. In practice though, it is pretty common to consume third party libraries (produced by others), and you would expect things to work as long as some basic compatibility requirements are met, wouldn't you ?

Comment: If you are referring to the standard library,  version of the library (`libstdc++`) and the compiler are often pretty closely closely coupled - each make assumptions or use specific implementation details/hooks of the other.    If you're referring to third-party libraries (assuming same ABI) the "producer" of the library can usually work with more recent "consumers".   Older "consumers" are less likely to work with newer "producers".

Comment: This seems to be the result of a defect report against the standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0935r0.html A standard library version from before that was implemented and which used explicit instantiation (as libstdc++ does for `std::basic_stringstream<char>`) would not have the default constructor introduced by it. I am not sure what libstdc++'s policy on ABI breaks due to defect reports is, but my understanding of https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html is that only forward-compatibility is a goal.

Comment: *... and you would expect things to work as long as some basic compatibility requirements are met, wouldn't you?*  Yes, I would expect that to be the case.  My expectations include using the same compiler, with the same flags.

Comment: So it seems to me that the answer is not to use a library compiled against a newer version of libstdc++ on a system with an older version of libstdc++.

Comment: @user17732522: you're right, that might be the key additional requirement. So in a usage model where producers and consumers of libraries are independent, it's not enough to agree on C++ version and ABI, but it seems that versions of run-time libraries have to be specified too.....

Comment: The [gnu documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) is quite clear though: `Binaries with equivalent DT_SONAMEs are forward-compatible` while `releases incompatible with the previous one are explicitly noted`. There is no incompatibility noted between libstdc++.so.6.0.28 (gcc 10.1.0) and libstdc++.so.6.0.25 (gcc 8.1.0), but it sounds like I've just found one ?

Comment: @DaveC As explained under "Goals" _forward-compatible_ means that you can use a library compiled against an old libstdc++ on a system with a newer one. And if I understand correctly that should indeed always work if none of the exceptions mentioned on the page apply. But you are doing the reverse. Your library is compiled against a newer libstc++ than the one you link/run your program against.

Comment: Yes thanks it all makes sense ! So what I take from this, is that if I want to produce a library and distribute it, my strategy to maximize the compatibility with any potential consumers is to use the oldest possible GCC (as long as it meets other requirements like C++ version and ABI of course)

Comment: @DaveC I think it is not uncommon to also ship the libstdc++.so if the target system's libstdc++ version isn't well-known. The C standard library boundary is much more stable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242427/discussion-between-davec-and-user17732522).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it mean that in general, it is necessary but not sufficient for the
> producer and the consumer of a library to use the same C++ version (and the > same ABI) ?

Correct. Backwards/forwards compatibility is not defined just by the C++ language version used when compiling source code. Backwards/forwards compatibility is a complicated topic of its own. But I'll just give a simple contrived, example that illustrates some underlying concepts.

Let's simplify what a `std::string` is. It's basically a pointer, and the number of characters in the string:

```
namespace std {

    class string {
         char *chars;
         size_t nchars;
    public:
         // Constructors and other methods.
    };
}
```

The real `std::string` is somewhat more complicated (and would use symbol names that are reserved for C++ implementations, but that's immaterial). This is just a simplified illustration. `std::string` existed even before C++11. So, things roll along, over the years, and your C++ compiler has been updated to C++20. For whatever reason its C++ library decided to change this class slightly:

```
namespace std {

    class string {
         size_t nchars;
         char *chars;
    public:
         // Constructors and other methods.
    };
}
```

At this point you can choose to instruct your new C++ compiler to compile only at the C++11 language revision. This will allow only C++11 language features. However the resulting binary code still will not be binary-compatible with code that was built by an older version of the C++ compiler, which was compiled with an incompatible class layout.

In general: in order for C++ code built by a new compiler to be binary compatible with code built by an older compiler, an explicit compilation/configuration option would be needed. It's certainly possible that this is this might be the option that specifies the general C++ language version, but just doing that is not generally sufficient. All that does is instruct the compiler which language version to use for compiling the C++ code. Newer language versions obsolete/deprecate features from earlier versions, and the purpose of the language option is to ***allow source code written for an earlier version of the C++ standard*** to be compiled, by the ***current*** C++ compiler. This is not the same thing as backwards/forwards compatibility.